# How to calculate the numbers of the observations in quantiles?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, frequency, quantile

Consider I have a million of observations following Gamma distribution with parameters (3,5). I am able to find the quantiles using `summary()` but I am trying to find how many observations are between each red lines which were divided into 10 pieces?

```
a = rgamma(1e6, shape = 3, rate = 5)

summary(a)

  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.0053  0.3455  0.5351  0.6002  0.7845  4.4458
```

[image]

Comment: `q <- quantile(a, probs = seq(0,1,0.1))` will give you quantiles. Then you can `length( a[a<q[2]] )` to give you the number of obs in a given quantile

Comment: Assuming you are talking about deciles, you'll find that the first 10% contains 10% of the observations (100000), as does the 10-20% range, by definition.

Comment: I think I had a lack of explaining myself. Histogram of this data will give me a left-skewed distribution. I would like to break x-axis into say 10 pieces and would like to see how many observations fall in each 10 percent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `cut` with `table`:

```
table(cut(a, quantile(a, 0:10 / 10)))

# (0.00202,0.22]   (0.22,0.307]  (0.307,0.382]  (0.382,0.457]  (0.457,0.535]  (0.535,0.622] 
#          99999         100000         100000         100000         100000         100000 
#  (0.622,0.724]  (0.724,0.856]   (0.856,1.07]    (1.07,3.81] 
#         100000         100000         100000         100000
```

but given what quantiles are, that may be not very interesting. Perhaps you may want to try the theoretical quantiles as well:

```
table(cut(a, qgamma(0:10 / 10, 3, 5)))

#      (0,0.22]  (0.22,0.307] (0.307,0.383] (0.383,0.457] (0.457,0.535] (0.535,0.621] (0.621,0.723] 
#         99978        100114        100545         99843         99273         99644        100104 
# (0.723,0.856]  (0.856,1.06]    (1.06,Inf] 
#        100208         99883        100408
```

Not much more interesting since, if your data really does follow a gamma distribution and you have a bunch of observations, then you can be quite certain that there will be close to x% of data between q-th and (q+x)-th theoretical quantiles. In smaller samples the second approach can be interesting.

---

**Edit**: Given your updated question, it's clear that by 10%, 20% you don't mean quantiles. Assuming that the minimal value is 0 and the maximal is 2, if as 10% you consider 0.2, then you want

```
table(cut(a, seq(min(a), max(a), length = 10 + 1)))

# (0.00418,0.428]   (0.428,0.853]    (0.853,1.28]      (1.28,1.7]      (1.7,2.13]     (2.13,2.55] 
#          361734          436176          155332           37489            7651            1335 
#     (2.55,2.97]      (2.97,3.4]      (3.4,3.82]     (3.82,4.25] 
#             231              38              11               2
```

Comment: Thanks Julius Vainora but sorry I am actually talking about to break the x-axis of the histogram into 10 pieces and would like to find how many observations fall into each piece.

Comment: @Justin, if you break them according to quantiles, then the answer is still the same, isn't it? I added another guess what you may have in mind.

Comment: @Justin, indeed my last line of code is what you want. It divides the range of `a` into 10 equal pieces and computes what you want.

Comment: I just updated the question added a plot. For instance, there should be fewer numbers of observations in the first interval and more observations in the second interval and so on, then, they will start decreasing again.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I mean