# How to include number of observations in each quartile of boxplot using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot

I am plotting a box-plot to see the distribution of the variable. I am also interested in seeing the number of observations in each quartile. Is there any way to add the number of observations in each quartile to the boxplot along with the values of quartiles?

I included some code below which can generate box-plot with the values of quartiles.

```r
df <- datasets::iris
boxplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, position = "dodge", fill = "red") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(geom = "label_repel", fun.y = quantile, aes(label = ..y..),
               position = position_nudge(x = -0.1), size = 3) +
  ggtitle("") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab('Sepal.Length')
```

I expect the values of quartiles on the left-hand side of the plot and the number of observations on the right-hand side of the plot if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would be one possibility. I always prefer to have my additional data as an extra data frame, because this gives me more control on what is how calculated.

Counting made with some inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451575

```r
quantile_counts=function(x){
 df= data.frame(label=table(cut(x, quantile(x))),
             label_pos=diff(quantile(x))/2+quantile(x)[1:4])
 return(df)
}

df_quantile_counts=quantile_counts(df$Sepal.Length)

boxplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, position = "dodge", fill = "red") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(geom = "label", fun.y = quantile, aes(label = ..y..),
               position = position_nudge(x = -0.1), size = 3) +
  geom_text(data=df_quantile_counts,aes(x="",y=label_pos,label = label.Freq),
            position = position_nudge(x = +0.1), size = 3) +
  ggtitle("") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab('Sepal.Length')
```

HTH, Tobi

Comment: This answer is correct if each cut point is unique. My data was kind of skewed and some cut points were the same (such as the first and second cut points were the same). I needed to take the unique values to calculate the number of observations in each quartile. Another point is related to usage of `cut` function which does not include the starting point (low bound, high bound]. In order to include the starting point, I have used the `cut2` function from the `Hmisc` package. I could include my edited function in below. Nevertheless, your answer was very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@TobiO 's answer is correct. But, my data was kind of skewed and some cut points were the same (such as the first and second cut points were the same). I needed to take the unique values to calculate the number of observations in each quartile. Another point is related to usage of `cut` function which does not include the starting point (low bound, high bound]. In order to include the starting point, I have used the `cut2` function from the `Hmisc` package. I included a `label_pos_extension` line in order to prevent the overlap of label/text for the quartiles whose cut points are very close to each other. `geom_text_repel` did not work for preventing the overlaps.

```
quantile_counts2 <- function(x){
  label_pos_extension <- c(0,3,4,0)
  if(length(unique(quantile(x))) < 5){
    df <- data.frame(label = table(cut2(x, g = 4)),
                 label_pos =  c(0, diff(unique(quantile(x))) / 2 + quantile(x)[1:length(unique(quantile(x)))-1]) + label_pos_extension[1:length(unique(quantile(x)))])
  } else {
    df <- data.frame(label = table(cut2(x, g = 4)),
                 label_pos = diff(quantile(x)) / 2 + quantile(x)[1:4] + label_pos_extension)
  } return(df)
}
```

PS. I tried to put my edited function in comment but, it did not work.